# How do I flag a question as possible duplicate?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I tried putting "Possible Duplicate" in the block quote, but my answer got converted to a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314289/ef-migrations-in-business-project-used-by-several-applications).

I am sure this question itself is a possible duplicate - I just can't find the one it is duplicating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click the <kbd>flag</kbd> button (which is just right of the <kbd>edit</kbd> one), then choose the option "The question doesn't belong here".

You will then get to this screen:

[image: Flag duplicate]

All you have to do is enter the URL of the possible duplicate, click the <kbd>Flag Question</kbd>, and you are done!

Answer (score 4):

First, if you know it is  a duplicate, don't answer it.  Any answer belongs on the duplicate question.  And don't try to manually add duplicate info, once the question is close it will be added automatically.

1. **To flag you first need to click the flag link:**
   [image]
2. **Then select "it doesn't belong here or is duplicate"**
   [image]
3. **Next select "duplicate"**
   [image]
4. **And finally enter the duplicate info by selecting the question below or entering the exact link or question id in the text box**
   [image]

Comment: Nice freehand circles.  +1.